# how to use docker in development

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and I have done some ground work on docker like how to build a image, how to create a container, what is dockerfile.yml, docker-compose.yml file does etc. I have done my practice in my local machine. I am having following questions when it is coming to real time development using docker.

1) Does each developer in a team has to do development on docker and create images in their local machine and push it to docker registry ? or developers work without docker and one person will be creating final image from the committed code?

2) For each release, do we maintain the container or an image for that release?

3) what is the best practice to maintain the database means do we incorporate the database in image and build the container or we include only application related things and build image and container, and this container will communicate to database which is in outside container or physical database server ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Questions like these generally do not have a definitive answer. It depends heavily on your company, your team, the tooling that is being used, the software stack, etc. The best thing to do would be to lean on the senior development resources and senior technical leadership in your organization to help shape the answers to questions like these.

Take the following answers with a silo of salt as there is no way to answer these kinds of questions definitively.

1) Depends on what is most convenient for the developers and what language you are using. Some developers find an all container workflow to be convenient, some developers find they can iterate faster with their existing IDE/CLI workflow and test against running container images last.

In most cases you will want to let CI/CD tooling take care of the builds that are intended for production.

2) Yes. You can use container tagging for this purpose.

3) Running databases in containers is possible, but unless your team is experienced with containers and container orchestration I would leave the databases on traditional bare-metal or VMs.

Containers are a fancy wrapper around a single linux process. Generally the rule of thumb is one container for one process. You should not be combining multiple things in a single container. (This story gets slightly more complicated when you go to something like Red Hat OpenShift or Kubernetes as the discussion revolves around how many containers per pod).

Answer (score 1):

1. The setup I'm used to is that developers mostly ignore Docker, until they need it to deploy.  Tools like Node's `node_modules` directory or Python's virtual environments can help isolate subproject from each other.  Any individual developer should be able to run `docker build` to build an image, but won't usually need to until the final stages of testing a particular change.  You should deploy a *continuous integration* system and that will take responsibility for testing and building a final Docker image of each commit.
2. You never "maintain containers".  If a container goes wrong, delete it and start a new one.  Your CI system should build an image for each release, and you should deploy a *registry* to hold these.
3. You should never keep the database in the same container as the application.  (See the previous point about routinely deleting containers.)  My experience has generally been that production databases are important and special enough to merit their own dedicated non-Docker hosts, but there's nothing actually wrong with running a database in Docker; just make sure you know how to do backups and restores and migrations and whatever else on it.

There's no technical reason you can't use Docker Compose for production, but if you wind up needing to deploy your application on more than one physical server you might find it limiting.  Kubernetes is more complex but seems to be the current winner in this space; Docker Swarm has some momentum; Hashicorp Nomad is out there; or you can build a manual deployment system by hand.  (Note that at least Kubernetes and Nomad are both very big on the "something changed so I'm going to delete and recreate a container" concept, and both make it extremely tricky to do live development in a quasi-production setup.)

Also note that where I say "deploy" there are public-cloud versions of all of these things (Docker Hub, CircleCI, end-to-end solutions including a registry and Kubernetes built on top of AWS or Azure or GCP) and if you're comfortable with the cost-to-effort tradeoff and the implications of using an external service in your build/deploy chain then these can help you get started faster

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer, David. I have few doubts on this. 
1) As you said the image won't be build until the final stage of testing is completed, but when I googled about docker the main reason to use docker is "application works on development machine, but ain't on testing machine". So giving regular build to testing without container is correct or not. Please bare me if this does not make sense. 
2) I do not understand Kubernetes, docker swarm. What and where are they used?

Comment: (1) A typical "Docker for development" setup replaces everything the standard image build sequence does with files from a developer's desktop; you get all of the disadvantages of not working "locally" (IDEs and debuggers work badly, file permissions are a challenge) and have something vastly different from a production build.  (2) You want one of these solutions when you need to deploy a container-based solution in an environment with multiple hosts and with multiple redundant copies of each container; they are much more production things than development.

Comment: Thanks for the information. David I have done some sample work on volume map. But all that I have done is from cmd prompt. I am trying to use volume keyword in dockerfile.yml file for mapping local folder to container, but I am having no luck. I googled a lot, but all are using either powershell or cmd prompt. I want to do it from dockerfile.yml. Please guide me on this. A few examples will be helpful.